# Доступ к членам экземпляра класса, возвращенном функцией

Tags: c#, ооп, функции, классы

```
 class API
 {          
      public API.EmailsList GetEmails()
      { 
          return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<API.EmailsList>("...");
      }
    
      public class EmailsList
      {
    
          public class Body
          {
              public int created { get; set; }
              public string alias { get; set; }
              public string folder { get; set; }
    
          }
    
      }
}
```

...

```
API api = new API();
var f = api.GetEmails();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять, почему я не могу получить доступ к экземпляру класса API.EmailsList, который возвращается в переменную f?

Comment: Внутри класса `EmailsList` нет членов: ни одного свойства, поля, метода. Класс `Body` просто объявлен внутри.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, может быть ответом? :)

Comment: Все, въехал. Не выспался просто XD

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо @AlexanderPetrov !

> Внутри класса EmailsList нет членов: ни одного свойства, поля, метода. Класс Body просто объявлен внутри.